# Google Drive 403 'Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup' (SOLVED)

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have an application that stores `app-database.db` file in user's Google Drive `appDataFolder`. The app is not published yet, so I'm the only user using the app currently.

`API key` and `OAuth Client ID` for both `debug` and `release` build types are generated in `Google Cloud Console`. Project is added to `Firebase Console` and `google-services.json` file is added to the main module folder of the application.

`OAuth Contest` is completed, its set to `In Production` and added scopes are `.../auth/drive.appdata` and `.../auth/drive.file` which both are `non-sensitive scopes`, so `Verification not required`. Also `Google Drive API` is **enabled** in `Google Cloud Console`.

Sending user to sign in screen like this:

```
val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
  .requestScopes(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
  .requestScopes(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA))
  .requestEmail()
  .build()
startActivityForResult(GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions).signInIntent, SIGN_IN_REQ_CODE)
```

Checking signin result like this:

```
GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
  .addOnSuccessListener { account: GoogleSignInAccount ->
    if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, *scopes)) {
      val drive = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this@SomeActivity, credentialScopes)
            .apply { selectedAccount = account.account }
            .let {
               Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), GsonFactory(), it)
                  .setApplicationName("APP_NAME_FROM_CONTEST_SCREEN")
                  .build()
            }
            // ...
    } else {
       GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(this@SomeActivity, PERMISSIONS_REQ_CODE, account, *scopes)
    }
  }.addOnFailureListener {
    // ...
  }

private val scopes = arrayOf(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE), Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA), Scope(Scopes.PROFILE), Scope(Scopes.OPEN_ID), Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
private val credentialScopes = listOf(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA)
```

Now when I try to upload or download file from/to any folder using `Drive API Client v3` it works perfectly in **`debug build`**. But in **`release build`** I'm getting:

```
403 Forbidden
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
      "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
      "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
    }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
```

So whats the problem? It works in `debug` and not in `release` although keys for both types are added inside the console. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I had set `minifyEnabled` to `true`, so for me the problem was proguard rules. Adding proguard rules fixed the problem.

```
# Needed to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-keepclassmembers class * { @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>; }

# Needed by google-http-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**

# Needed by google-api-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**

# Needed by google-play-services when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Comment: **Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.** means that you haven't sent a authorization header and a bearer token with your request to the api.    You appear to be trying to mix signin and Oauth2.  They are two different things.  try using the Google api java client library  maybe something like this https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/integrating-google-drive-api-in-android-applications-18024f42391c

Comment: @DalmTo using the same library and doing the same steps explained in the link above, but the same exception is thrown in **release** build. The question is if theres any problem with headers or accessToken, how the code works perfectly in debug build.